# How to refresh the form fields and view after a different app update's the database? Django, Python

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I have 2 apps, 2 forms, the checkboxes in form 1 depend on the values stored in Model 2 (by form2).
The problem is, when I add a new object in Model 2 (form 2), and go to Form 1, the checkboxes do not update.

I've tried all i could, please let me know what I'm doing wrong, and if there's a way to achieve this.

This if form-1, where the form fields depend on the distinct values of 'queue_names' present in the QueueStatusModel (a different app)

```
class NewInvestigatorForm(forms.ModelForm):

queues_queryset = QueueStatusModel.objects.order_by().values('queue_name').distinct()
queue_name_list = []

for i in queues_queryset:
    x = i.get("queue_name")
    queue_name_list.append( (x,x) )
    
active_qs = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    choices = queue_name_list,
    widget  = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
)

class Meta:
    model = PriorityModel
    fields = [
        'login',
        'core',
        'active_qs',
        'priority'
    ]
```

This is form-2, where I add a new 'queue_name':

```
class AddNewQueue(forms.ModelForm):

queue_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Queue Name", "size":60}))
class Meta:

    model = QueueStatusModel
    fields = [
        'queue_name'
    ]

def clean_queue_name(self, *args, **kwargs):
    queue_name = self.cleaned_data.get("queue_name")

    if " " in queue_name:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Queue names cannot contain space")
    else:
        return queue_name
```

Queue Status Model, where the queue related info is stored:

```
class QueueStatusModel(models.Model):

queue_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
volume = models.IntegerField()
active_investigators = models.IntegerField()
```

New Investigator related Model:

```
class PriorityModel(models.Model):

login = models.CharField(max_length=15)
core = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=[("", ""), ("", "")])


active_qs = models.CharField(max_length=500)

priority = models.CharField(max_length=500,
                        choices=[("SLA","SLA"), ("volume","Volume"), ("custom","Custom")]
                        )
custom_priority = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('core', '-login')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution using JavaScript.
Now i'm rendering the "active_qs" field as hidden in the HTML, and creating checkboxes using javascript, with their values as all the queues passed from the view.
The value of all the selected checkboxes I store in an array. When I press Submit on the form, the value of the 'active_qs' hidden text field gets updated with the array, and I can then access this in the form.cleaned_data.

Code to create checkboxes using the django queryset data:

```
var available_queues = {{ queue_set_JS|safe }}
for (available_q of available_queues){
    const node = document.createElement("li");
    node.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="id-' + available_q.queue_name + '" class="queue_li" value="' + available_q.queue_name + '"><label for="id-' + available_q.queue_name + '">'+ available_q.queue_name +'</label>';
    qs_ul.append(node) 
}
```

//qs_ul is a ul I created in the HTML template where this checkbox will be pushed as an li

To run a JS function when you click Submit on the form you can use:

```
        <input type="submit" class="form-submit-btn" onclick="my_func2();" value="Submit">
```

And you can update the value of the hidden field of 'active_qs' in my_func2()

```
function my_func2(){
    active_qs_text_field.setAttribute("value", final_queue_list.join(", "))
}
```

Where active_qs_text_field is previously defined as:

```
    const active_qs_text_field = document.querySelector("#id_active_qs")
```